# How to update a document using ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I get the following list of documents back from MongoDB when I find for `"campaignID":"DEMO-1"`.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "56be0e8b3cf8a2d4f87ddb97"
    },
    "campaignID": "DEMO-1",
    "revision": 1,
    "action": [
      "kick",
      "punch"
    ],

    "transactionID": 20160212095539543
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "56c178215886447ea261710f"
    },
    "transactionID": 20160215000257159,
    "campaignID": "DEMO-1",
    "revision": 2,
    "action": [
      "kick"
    ],
    "transactionID": 20160212095539578
  }
]
```

Now, what I am trying to do here is for a given `campaignID` I need to find all its versions (revision in my case) and modify the `action` field to `dead` of type String. I read the docs and the examples they have is too simple not too helpful in my case. This is what the docs say:

```
val selector = BSONDocument("name" -> "Jack")

val modifier = BSONDocument(
  "$set" -> BSONDocument(
    "lastName" -> "London",
    "firstName" -> "Jack"),
    "$unset" -> BSONDocument(
      "name" -> 1))

// get a future update
val futureUpdate = collection.update(selector, modifier)
```

I can't just follow the docs because its easy to create a new BSON document and use it to modify following the BSON structure by hardcoding the exact fields. In my case I need to find the documents first and then modify the `action` field on the fly because unlike the docs, my `action` field can have different values.

Here's my code so far which obviously does not compile:

```
def updateDocument(campaignID: String) ={
    val timeout = scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds")
    val collection = db.collection[BSONCollection](collectionName)
    val selector = BSONDocument("action" -> "dead")
    val modifier = collection.find(BSONDocument("campaignID" -> campaignID)).cursor[BSONDocument]().collect[List]()
    val updatedResults = Await.result(modifier, timeout)
    val mod = BSONDocument(
      "$set" -> updatedResults(0),
      "$unset" -> BSONDocument(
        "action" -> **<???>** ))
    val futureUpdate = collection.update(selector, updatedResults(0))
    futureUpdate
  }
```

Comment: I think I was confused between the selector and modifier. I think my selector should be `"action" -> "[
      "kick",
      "punch"
    ]"` which is syntatically incorrect but I am not sure how to pass in a List. Also In the example, why was the name set again since it was already set to "Jack"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me as an answer to my own question. Thanks @cchantep for helping me out.

```
val collection = db.collection[BSONCollection](collectionName)
val selector = BSONDocument("campaignID" -> campaignID)
val mod = BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("action" -> "dead"))
val futureUpdate = collection.update(selector, mod, multi = true)
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I posted a question and provided an answer that actually fixed what I wanted to fix. This might help someone with similar concerns.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the [BSON documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/bson/overview.html), you can see `BSONArray` can be used to pass sequence of BSON values.

```
BSONDocument("action" -> BSONArray("kick", "punch"))
```

If you have `List[T]` as values, with `T` being provided a `BSONWriter[_ <: BSONValue, T]`, then this list can be converted as `BSONArray`.

```
BSONDocument("action" -> List("kick", "punch"))
// as `String` is provided a `BSONWriter`
```